# PhoneGap NativeControls on Retina Display

Tags: ios, cordova, retina-display

Wondering if anyone has had any experience using retina assets with the NativeControls iPhone plugin for tabbars? Using the plugin it's possible to set custom images for each tabbar button, but anything above 32x32px (from memory) becomes distorted. 32x32px icons are fine, but viewed on iPhone 4 retina display look pretty bad.

Somebody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a phonegap specific issue, you just need to create a high res icon for the retina display, as well as the normal resolution. You can read about that in the docs here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

```
img.png
img@2x.png
```